# Google App Engine (PHP) - redirected you too many times

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to work on redirecting to a page on Google App Engine because due to changes from php55 to php74, the script variable in app.yaml requires it to be set as auto (meaning I need to have an index.php set up). Because of that complication, I get an error where it says I get redirected too many times. I tested this on my local machine, but once I deploy it on GAE, it get that redirect issue.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php74

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
header("Location: login.php");
exit();
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include("header.inc");
?>

<?php

session_start();

use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;
use Google\Cloud\DataStore\DatastoreClient;

# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = '---';

# Instantiates a client
$datastore = new DatastoreClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

// Test to see if auth actually works
echo "Hello World!"

?>

<form method="post">
<!--    <div class="form-group">-->
<!--        <label for="username">Username</label>-->
<!--        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--    <div>-->
<!--        <div class="form-group">-->
<!--            <label for="password">Password</label>-->
<!--            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">-->
<!--        </div>-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--    <div-->
<!--    ">-->
<!--    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--    <div>-->
<!--        <button type="Register" href="register.php">Register</button>-->
<!--    </div>-->
<!--    </div>-->
</form>

<?php
include("footer.inc");
?>
```

Comment: Your index.php is "blindly" sending the user to login. My guess is that once the user logs in, the process repeats over and over.

Comment: I haven't made the login page functional yet, just all front-end stuff. I have made it so the login page is the index.php page instead just to prevent this issue from happening in the future. Thank you for the insight on my issue

Comment: I would recommend starting your application by following the [Quickstart for PHP 7 in the standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart). Then you can add more functionalities, once initial set up is working and tested.