# GCP App Engine app.yaml for PHP - not accessing resource files

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have a PHP script, and the main index.php is not on the root directory, it is inside root/src, I created an index.php in root that redirects to src/index.php, and I tried several app.yaml configurations, however whenever I deploy my app to GCP App Engine, I get too many redirects error. I tried this setup locally on my localhost/GCP Compute Engine VM, and it works perfectly, I am unable to get the app running on App Engine.

image 1: image of my web browser showing the infinite redirects as soon as I access the GAE

image 2: image of my root folder, contains the app.yaml, with its latest configuration,
and the index.php that redirects to the main index.php in root/src

[image]

[image]

How am I supposed to let the app.ymal access the main index.php and read the resources that are inside root/src, like logout.php/login.php icons.png etc?

Comment: I found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575307/google-app-engine-php-redirected-you-too-many-times). You are somehow entering a loop, when accessing `index.php` it redirects you to the same page and so on.

Comment: Well I even tried making a simple hello world in src/index.php, but still couldn't let the app to access it on GAE, this problem seems to be the one I am facing exactly, but it is not resolved as well..